# Get a VB6 variable's name as a string value

Tags: string, debugging, parsing, vb6

I would like to get a VB6 variable's name as a string value in order to handle it in a logging facility I am using like the following one (please check !!!VariableName!!!).

Is there any way to achieve this? I am pretty new to VB6 and I am supposed to maintain and debug existing old VB6 code.

```
Public Sub AddVariableValue2Log(ByVal checkDebug, _
                                ByVal sFunctionName As String, _
                                ByVal sVariableValue As String, _
                                ByVal sTimeStamp As String)

  If checkDebug Then
    Dim sLogPath As String
    sLogPath = "C:\Temp\Log_" & sTimeStamp & ".txt"

    Dim fn As Integer
    fn = FreeFile

    Open sLogPath For Append As #fn
    Write #fn, Now & "|" & sFunctionName & "|>>>!!!VariableName!!! value: [" & sVariableValue & "]"
    Close #fn
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 because I wish it *was* possible, but I don't believe it is.

Comment: You should try (and have tried)  
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=VB6+obtain+debug+info+programmatically+at+runtime  
It brings up a lot of earlier discussions about the same

Comment: @GermannArlington Thank you for the advice. Actually I was not so able to explain myself with Google as you have done. I used queries like "get VB6 variable name as a string value" on both Google and StackOverflow failing to find the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible in VB6. You have to pass name of the variable.

```
AddVariableValue2Log(True, "MyFunction", "MyVariable", MyVariable, Now())
```

Comment: Thank you! I suspected it, but I was not able to find any useful information about it.